# Alembic Error : No 'script_location' key found in configuration

Tags: python, alembic

alembic.ini file:

```
[alembic]  
#path to migration scripts  
script_location = migrations
```

Script I am running:

```
alembic -n dev revision --autogenerate -m "alembic_migration_file"
```

My project directory:

```
|-migrations  
|--versions  
|----dev  
|----uat
```

I am running above script, not sure why it's not able to find the script_location from alembic config file.

Comment: Why do you think that it should be using your `alembic.ini` file?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the content of the configuration file is incompatible with the invocation.

From the Alembic 1.11.2 help text:

```
$ alembic --help
[...]
  -n NAME, --name NAME  Name of section in .ini file to use for Alembic config
```

thus, `-n dev` command line argument tells Alembic to read a `[dev]` section in the config file, but the provided `alembic.ini` file contains an `[alembic]` section instead, so Alembic is not able to determine its configuration.

To fix the problem, either rename `[alembic]` to `[dev]` in the `alembic.ini` file, or remove the `-n dev` argument from the invocation.